# How do I limit access to a GAE Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-datastore

I'm New to GAE and am trying to wrap my head around how to limit what a user can see in the Datastore. So far the only oauth examples I've found gives me access to the function or not;

if (user == null) throw new UnauthorizedException("User is Not Valid");

So just for a simple example, lets say a logged in user can add an Author and a BookTitle to kind books and the insert automatically added the users email or googleID.

If I wanted to only let this user see his books then on a get I would add googleid to the filter. That's easy enough. (is it the best way?)

But what if I want people that are Admin_user to be able to see all books. And People who are Author_admins to only see books that have certain authors. (It's a contrived example eh)

Do I basically just control data based on datastore filters. Have a Kind called people with lists of Kinds and entities they are aloud to see or is there a better way?

Comment: The question is not really related to app engine, look for tutorials about how to build a simple application with multiple users and roles.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to use datastore without app engine and I can't see how datastore has any security built into it. So as far as I can see app engine is very reinvent to questions about implementing datastore. 

Thank you very much for the googling advice. I didn't think of that.

Comment: @RonH, to use datastore w/o app engine, see https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs -- and yes it has security built-in, as you need credentials to access it, see https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/javadoc/ about getServiceAccountCredential for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for multitenancy using different namespaces for different types of users. Here is the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy

Comment: That is a good place to start. Thank you! Does anyone know of any really good tutorials on multitenancy?  The google provided Guest book is ok but something else might be better.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260134/how-to-handle-permissions-in-gae-application) was also very helpful.

Comment: And so was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641412/how-to-use-rbac-or-access-control-on-google-app-engine)

Comment: Glad to hear that! Let me know how you are finally implementing this design in your application.